# Representation theory& module

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules, group-actions

$V$ is a left $R$ module, how do you understand the ring homomorphism 
$$\rho_{V}:R \to End_Z(V)$$

I know that it is like a group acting on sets, but it is very easy to understand like a group $S_n$ act on set $X$ for permutation, so how can you understand $End_Z(V)$ under this scenario ?

And also since this  has something to do with representation theory, so (if I understand correctly), $End_Z(V)$ can be think as all linear transformation, so  what about the element of $R$ here ? Seems that I haven't build a bridge between rings and its effects on modules so far...

Comment: Each ring element acts like an endomorphism. The map $\rho_V$ sends a ring element to the precise endomorphism it acts like. This is the exact same as with group actions. Each group element acts like a function. The map $G\to{\rm Perm}(X)$ sends a group element to the function it acts like. Except now, not only does ring multiplication correspond to function composition, ring addition corresponds to pointwise addition of functions.

Comment: Can all endomorphism of V be expressed as some function \lambda_v ?

Comment: By definition an endomorphism of an abelian group is a certain type of function (satisfying yadda yadda). What do you mean by $\lambda_V$? Are you asking if the map $R\to{\rm End}_Z(V)$ is surjective? Is there any reason to expect it to be? Is $G\to{\rm Perm}(X)$ surjective in the case of group actions?

Comment: That is typo...I mean \lambda_r (v), which is the element in End_Z (V), since the function \rho_{V}:R \to End_Z(V) can be defined as r \to \lambda_r (V)

Comment: it seems to me you are asking surjectivity of $\rho_V$.  Just put $R=k$ a field, ask yourself if a map $k$-linear map $k\to End_k(V)$ with $V$ a $k$-vector space (=$k$-module) is necessarily surjective.